# Illustrator cc: gradient tool — How to take color from the image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, eyedropper

- At first I tried the trick with dragging eyedropper, as in Flash 5 (very simple way).
- Then i tried to use a eyedropper.

[image: How to take color from the image?]

**Update solution**
I still can not believe that this is the quickest way, I'm sad :(

1. Select object
2. Select *slider in Gradient panel*
3. Eyedropper tool — *Shift+Click*

Or second way, thx joojaa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool will not become active in Illustrator so it can not do this the way you like. But you get almost the same effect with one drag and click more:

- After you click with the color picker, drag that color from the color well into the gradient. This will reactivate the new gradient that is what you want.

Admittedly this is a bit inferior but its the best you can do. In case of not sampling a image you can just drag and drop the object in.

Comment: Maybe there is a plug or for some better solution?

Comment: @ruxman maybe, but i haven't seen one. Every design has some downsides.

Answer (score 6):

*I had a hard time understanding the proposed solution so I rewrote it.*

If you have a selected object filled with a gradient and you want to use the eyedropper to update the colors of the gradient, you can:

1. Select (click on) the gradient slider you wish to modify
2. Activate the eyedropper tool (i or tool palette)
3. **SHIFT** click on the color you want to sample, updating the gradient slider.

Comment: God knows why Adobe made it necessary to hold down the shift key. There must be one user out of a thousand that knows this shortcut.

Comment: Props for clarity. Accepted answer is difficult to understand.